# Is LWIP integrated with USB in Raspberry?

Tags: networking, usb

Can I add to a Raspberry Pi (2, 3?) an usb dongle (to add a network interface) and then install LWIP to manage that connection using LWIP code?

LWIP is a IP/TCP Open stack (https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/) to be able to manage both interfaces and create different projects. I'm not sure if it would recognize Raspberry interfaces (integrated or USB).

Comment: Lwip would need to o be integrated into the kernel since kernel runs the tcpip stack , OR one can expose a raw device and try to use lwip in user space maybe on top of a MAC driver so kernel can still manage the physical interface  , or in baremetal in which case you need to bring usb bus and device drivers. In either case the integration is on you unless someone has a kernel patched to use lwip

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using **Raspbian**. Yes, you can just plug in an USB/wired ethernet dongle and/or an USB/wifi dongle and will get additional interfaces **eth1** and/or **wlan1** out of the box if the dongle are supported by Raspbian. About LWIP I can't say much because I haven't any experience with it and I'm afraid you hardly will find one here on this site. The best would be you try it and make an answer here to share it.

Comment: Thanks, by LWIP I mean this IP/TCP Open stack (https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/) to be able to manage both interfaces and create different projects. I'm not sure if it would recognize Raspberry interfaces (integrated or USB)